# OpenStreetMap - Extract City and Administrative Boundaries from the Selected Country

Tags: openstreetmap

How can I export a list of cities with coordinates from a selected
country, along with a list of districts and other administrative boundaries?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `osmnx` module to extract your desired data:

- first do:

```
pip install osmnx
```

- then:

```
import osmnx as ox

# Specify the name of the country or city (e.g., "France" or "Paris, France")
place_name = "France"  # Replace with your desired country or city name

# Fetch administrative boundaries and other places from OpenStreetMap
graph = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type='all', which_result=1)

# Get a GeoDataFrame of all cities
cities = ox.geometries_from_place(place_name, tags={'place': ['city', 'town', 'village', 'hamlet']})

# Get a GeoDataFrame of administrative boundaries
admin_boundaries = ox.geometries_from_place(place_name, tags={'boundary': 'administrative'})

# Export the data to CSV files
cities.to_csv('cities.csv')
admin_boundaries.to_csv('admin_boundaries.csv')
```

The output will be saved in `csv` files.

You can get more ideas in the `osmnx` documentation from here: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: Note that the `geometries` module and functions were renamed `features` a while back and that old naming is deprecated.